# Monitoring switch port (service) per interface

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, monitoring, snmp

My actual goal is to monitor the traffic going through a zyxel USG60 switch (v4.15). For that I use zabbix.

The problem I got is that I actually monitor the interfaces of the switch, but I need to go deeper (if you know what I mean), in the term that my boss asked me if I could monitor on each interface, the different traffic port by port (I mean service, like port 80 is for http), to check precisely who is using bandwidth and for what.

I tried to see if snmp can do that, but it seems it didn't go further the interface level. Since I don't know where to start or search, I need your help and advice.

One last precision, the monitoring server will be run under ubuntu 14.04 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to collect additional data using **NetFlow/sFlow** protocols to get the detailed traffic information.